# Permissions help with using action.forward token in an email

Tags: civimail, permissions, tokens, acl

I want to add a forward to a friend at the bottom of an email.  When recipient clicks they see the "enter up to 5 email address" page however if they are a non-authenticated user they get a  Undefined property error and a not authorized error.  The email is sent correctly.  [image: screen capture of the errors returned]
Is there a way to send them to a public page and does anyone know what the  Undefined property error is.  Thanks

Civi 5.2.1 . on Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 'access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages' permission set for anonymous user.

Comment: Thanks, I do have it set that way.